# Is there a library implemented RangeDict in python?

Tags: python

There is a `RangeMap` implementation in `guava` which can be used for mapping  range to object.

Is there a similar library in python? I did not find one yet by googling.

To make question more clear, the `RangeDict` I mean a collection support usage like:

```
rd = RangeDict()
rd[[1,2]] = 'A'
rd[[11,22]] = 'B'
print rd[1] # A
print rd[12] # B
print 23 in rd # False
print 18 in rd # True
```

**EIDT:**

Since there seems no such module, I wrote one [here](https://github.com/WKPlus/rangedict), you can install it by `pip install rangedict` and use it like this:

```
>>> from rangedict import RangeDict
>>> rd = RangeDict()
>>> rd[(1, 2)] = 1
>>> rd[(3, 3)] = 3
>>> rd[(5, 7)] = 5
>>> print rd[6]
5
>>> 3 in rd
True
>>> del rd[(3, 3)]
>>> 3 in rd
False
```

Comment: Why did you edit your question, but not address the fundamental problem with it, which is covered in item #4 here http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic?  Your question is fine, except for one thing: it doesn't belong here because the rules say it doesn't.   You could avoid closure of your question if you get rid of the request for a library, and instead explore implementation code.

Comment: @GreenAsJade OK, I will close it.

Answer (score 4):

I quickly came up with this that satisfies your four assertions.

```
import collections

class RangeDict(collections.MutableMapping):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.store = dict()
        self.update(dict(*args, **kwargs))

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.store[self.transform_key(key)]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.store[key] = value

    # two possible behaviours
    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del self.store[self.transform_key(key)]
        # del self.store[key]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.store)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.store)

    def transform_key(self, key):
        for k in self.iterkeys():
            if k[0] <= key <= k[1]:
                return k
        return key # this behaviour would need to be better defined
```

You would however need to use tuples as keys (immutable), not lists (mutable).

```
rd = RangeDict()
rd[(1,2)] = 'A'
rd[(11,22)] = 'B'
```

Comment: Why don't you transform the keys to tuples yourself? And why the double underscores to __keytransform__?

Comment: python mappings/dicts require hashable objects for keys, and I will not hide that away, one could if he wanted to of course. I renamed the keytransform method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But IMHO it's the simplest implementation in which most operations will have a O(n) complexity.

Comment: @WKPlus: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @WKPlus where would that be O(n)? It's key-length * O(1), which is again O(1)

Comment: @deets n is the key length. I am wondering is there a implementation based on range tree, it will have O(logn) complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and easy:

```
class RangeDict():
    def __init__(self):
        self._dict = {}

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        for k, v in self._dict.items():
            if k[0] <= key < k[1]:
                return v
        raise KeyError("Key not found!")

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if len(key) == 2:
            if key[0] < key[1]:
                self._dict.__setitem__((key[0], key[1]), value)

    def __contains__(self, key):
        try:
            return bool(self.__getitem__(key))
        except KeyError:
            return False

rd = RangeDict()
rd[[1, 2]] = 'A'
rd[[11, 22]] = 'B'
print(rd[1])  # A
print(rd[18])  # B
print(23 in rd)  # False
print(18 in rd)  # True
```